# Type mismatch during Gson deserialize json response with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am trying to serialize the json response below, but I am unsure how to do it.

This is the Json my backend returns:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Dummy section, should not be seen",
    "type": "dummy_test",
    "metadata": []
  },
    {
    "title": "Title1",
    "type": "categories_products",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "id": "1272"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Title2",
    "type": "categories_products",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "id": "996"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my ExploreItem class:

```
data class ExploreItem(
    @SerializedName("metadata") val metadata: List<Metadata> = listOf(),
    @SerializedName("title") val title: String = "",
    @SerializedName("type") val type: String = ""
) {
    enum class ExploreItemType(val value: String) {
        @SerializedName("unknown")
        UNKNOWN("unknown"),

        @SerializedName("other_companies")
        OTHER_COMPANIES("other_companies"),

        @SerializedName("categories_products")
        CATEGORIES_PRODUCTS("categories_products"),

        @SerializedName("popular_categories")
        POPULAR_CATEGORIES("popular_categories")
    }
}

data class Metadata(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String = ""
)
```

And now I am trying to serialize it in the repository like this:

```
Serializer.defaultJsonParser.fromJson(response.body!!.string(),ExploreItem::class.java )
```

but it doesn't work because it's expecting a list of ExploreItem. How can I rewrite the serializer expression to parse it into a list?

Comment: what is your stack trace?

Comment: Type mismatch. Required:List<ExploreItem> Found:ExploreItem! that's the error that the serializer line shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error

> Type mismatch. Required:List Found:ExploreItem!

Post errors is very important, Gson is telling you that it wants a List and not an object of `ExploreItem`.

In other words, you are telling to Gson with the call `Serializer.defaultJsonParser.fromJson(response.body!!.string(),ExploreItem::class.java )`

"Hey Gson, from the string I want an object `ExploreItem`", and Gson is telling you "Hey my friend, you string start with `[ ]` for sure it is a list of something and not a single object."

You need to pass in the `Serializer.defaultJsonParser.fromJson(response.body!!.string(),List<ExploreItem>::class.java)`

P.s: I'm not sure about the Kotlin syntax